# How to make web scraping page continuously working

Tags: php, web-scraping

Let's say I've createad a web scraping PHP page (`getdata.php`) that gets content of a specific website pages by cUrl, than saves some useful info to a txt file or database.

pseudo code of `getdata.php`,

```
min = get latest search id from database
max = 1.000.000 (yes one million different pages)

while (min < max) {

  url = "http://www.website.com/page.php?id=".$min
  content = getContentFromURL(url)
  saveUsefulInfoToDb(content)
  min++
  set latest search id as min in database
}
```

It's OK, the proccess is,

1. Open `getdata.php` on browser
2. Wait
3. Still wait, because there is about one million pages will be scraped.
4. Wait
5. And finally request time out.
6. Fail

So the problem is I don't know how can I make this proccess reasonable. opening page on a browser and waiting for it to finish scraping URLs, I think It's a really bad practice.

How can I make getdata.php runnable in background like cron?

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: why can't you have a cron job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in the top of the code

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

Then use a cron to fire it up each day or whenever it needs to.  You definitely want this to be a background process and not a web page.  Those two lines will allow it to run indefinitely as a web page or cmd line script.  If you want to make it as a web page you can still use the cron to 'fire' it off with a line like

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/curl "http://yoursite.com/getdata.php" >> "/var/www/errors.log"
```

a bit of advice since I have done this many times: definitely make a logging function to print to a file so that you can see what it is doing as it runs or you will have no visibility and program into the php file a kill switch so you can tell it to stop running without having to use unix top or restart apache.  It is probably a good idea to hard code in a kill time that it will stop if after a certain hour lest it run longer than a day and a second instance starts up and you have several running at once.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @hackartists answer, I would add not to invoke this PHP page through the browser at all.  Instead, invoke it from the command line

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php

> Open getdata.php on browser

should be

> Schedule getdata.php to run from the command line using cron

Additionally, log success or failure so that you can setup some log file monitoring to know when your web scraping job fails (after all, you don't want to sit in front of a browser daily and monitor this yourself).